# Dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I am looking to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. While installing Ubuntu from Live CD, I see the whole hard disk as free space even though Windows 8 is already installed and there are 3 partitions.

Could someone guide me on how to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Exit the Ubuntu installer and then open up the Gparted partition editor.Take a screenshot of it and then upload it to imgur.com.Finally provide the uploaded link here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install ubuntu alongside windows 8 by reading the steps found on help.ubuntu. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

I also found a helpful link that explains with pictures the steps to take on proceeding with this dual boot. 
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Both of the mention backing up your windows partition and re-sizing the partition table. Be sure to read through those ares closely. Hope this helps.